# How to insert a new revoked certificate into the .crl file?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, itext7

I want to have revoked certificate list, I create a CRL using C# code below, a CRL file is D:\Log\MyCRL.crl

```
Create_Revocation_List(@"D:\Log\developer1.pfx", "password");
Create_Revocation_List(@"D:\Log\developer2.pfx", "password");
Create_Revocation_List(@"D:\Log\developer3.pfx", "password");
```

**Create_Revocation_List**

```
            var issuerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(cert, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            var certCA = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(issuerCertificate);
            var issuerName = issuerCertificate.Subject;

            X509V2CrlGenerator crlGen = new X509V2CrlGenerator();
            crlGen.SetIssuerDN(certCA.IssuerDN);
            crlGen.SetThisUpdate(DateTime.Now);

            var random = GetSecureRandom();
            var issuerKeyPair = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(issuerCertificate.PrivateKey);
            var issuerSerialNumber = new BigInteger(issuerCertificate.GetSerialNumber());

            string signatureAlgorithm = Models.BouncyCastle.HashType.SHA512withRSA.ToString();
            ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory(signatureAlgorithm, issuerKeyPair.Private, random);

            crlGen.AddCrlEntry(new BigInteger(issuerCertificate.GetSerialNumber()), DateTime.Now, CrlReason.PrivilegeWithdrawn);

            crlGen.AddExtension(X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier,
                               false,
                               new AuthorityKeyIdentifierStructure(certCA));

            crlGen.AddExtension(X509Extensions.CrlNumber,
                               false,
                               new CrlNumber(new BigInteger(issuerCertificate.GetSerialNumber())));

            X509Crl crlTemp = crlGen.Generate(signatureFactory);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\log\MyCRL.crl", crlTemp.GetEncoded());
```

Why it shows only 1 revoked certificate but if I open the .crl file with notepad, I see there are 3 revoked certificates in base64 format.

[image]

[image: Only shows 1 revoked certificate]

many thanks in advance

Regards
Don

Comment: As you generate your own CRLs, you appear to be running an own PKI. Wouldn't it be better in such a case to use an existing PKI management suite? There is quite a lot to consider if one is coding everything oneself...

Comment: Your question asks "How to insert a new revoked certificate into the .crl file?" But in the comment you say "I am trying to read CRL Offline with iText7." Those are completely different things. Please focus a question on one issue.

Comment: sorry, my fault.. I have 2 questions posted...please ignore my previous comment

Comment: *"now I have another CRL that need to be inserted into that .crl file"* - do you mean you have another revocation you want to add to the list? Then call `crlGen.AddCrlEntry` twice, the second time with the data for the other revoked certificate. Or do you really want to add a whole CRL to your CRL? A CRL only has individual certificate revocation entries, not (sub)list entries.

Comment: if I open the .crl file with notepad, I see there are 3 revoked certificates in base64 format.. what I missed?

Comment: First of all, you call the file viewed in your editor *one CRL*; this is incorrect, that file contains a sequence of three CRLs, each apparently containing a single revoked certificate. Not all programs expect multiple CRLs in a file, probably your CRL viewer doesn't. Furthermore, I expect more issues; can you share your triple CRL file for analysis? I don't intend to type it in from your screen shot... ;)

Comment: https://apps.primteksolusindo.com/Log.zip

Comment: You appear to have found an answer yourself. Does it work for you or are there still open issues in respect to this question?

Comment: yes it works as expected .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hope I can help someone that also struggling with this..

```
        X509CrlParser xx = new X509CrlParser();
        X509Crl _ocrl = null;

        try
        {
            _ocrl = xx.ReadCrl(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Log\mycrl.crl"));
        }
        catch { }
        finally { }

        try
        {
            var issuerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\Log\myca.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            var certCA = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(issuerCertificate);
            var cakeypair = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(issuerCertificate.PrivateKey);
            var issuerName = issuerCertificate.Subject;

            X509V2CrlGenerator crlGen = new X509V2CrlGenerator();
            crlGen.SetIssuerDN(certCA.IssuerDN);
            crlGen.SetThisUpdate(DateTime.Now);

            string signatureAlgorithm = "SHA256withRSA";
            ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory(signatureAlgorithm, cakeypair.Private);

            var revokedCertificate = new X509Certificate2(_cert, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            var revoked = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(revokedCertificate);
            var revokedKeyPair = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(revokedCertificate.PrivateKey);
            var revokedSerialNumber = new BigInteger(revokedCertificate.GetSerialNumber());

            crlGen.AddCrlEntry(revokedSerialNumber, DateTime.Now, CrlReason.PrivilegeWithdrawn);

            if (_ocrl != null)
                crlGen.AddCrl(_ocrl);


            X509Crl _crl = crlGen.Generate(signatureFactory);

            byte[] _bb = _crl.GetEncoded();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\log\mycrl.crl", _bb);
```

[image]